# How to ensure the same version of a nuget package is used accross the whole Visual Studio solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

We have a really big Visual Studio solution(460+ projects in C# .NET 7), and I'm facing the following issue:
Depending on which project I built last, I don't have the same version of a library coming from nuget package.

In my case, it is an issue that in my solution, I've several project, that references different part of the Unity framework(`Unity.Configuration`, `Unity.Container`, `Unity.Abstractions`). And those parts of framework have also dependencies.
I hope this makes it clearer:

[image]

This is an issue for us, because since we have multiple executable that will get shipped in the same setup, we do build everthing in the same output folder. But even if this was not the case, the goal is still to keep our bundle minimal and not have 10 differents version of the same library.

Here, I cannot even make `My.Project.A` reference the 5.11.11 version of `Unity.Configuration`, because the latest version is the 5.11.2.

So, I know, that for this exact specific case, I could:

1. Make `My.Project.B` and `My.Project.C` referencing respectively the 5.11.5 and 5.11.2 versions
2. Make `My.Project.B` and `My.Project.C` referencing Unity.Configuration 5.11.2 even I don't need this specific package here
3. Make `My.Project.A` Reference the 5.11.11 version of Unity.Container

None of those solutions are nice or acceptable for us, because it:

- Require us to check the dependency list of all the projects(with third party tools because visual studio doesn't display easily the indirect references)
- Might break if a library gets updated

Is there a way to make VS trying to use the same version of the library? In my case, `Unity.Configuration` version 5.11.11 could totally match the `Unity.Configuration` versions constraints.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/introducing-central-package-management/

Comment: you may use an env-varibale with the exact version-number and use that within your package-references, e.g. `<PackageReference Include=MyPackage" Version="$(MyEnvVar)" />`

Comment: There are binding redirects that can be used to ensure the highest version of a library is used if there multiple candidates. These can be automatically generated (see project settings). So if project A references Project B you should get the 5.11.11 version. However, 460+ project seem extremely excessive, I would expect that this will affect the build times, nuget update times, etc.

Comment: @canton7 That's very interesting, thank you. But in my case, if I didn't have the `My.Project.C`. Nobody would reference directly the Unity.Abstractions, but I would still have to manually add which version can be used ? Also, is there a way to have Visual Studio doing this file maintenance?

Comment: @JonasH Yeah, we try to use them. But if I build only a part of my solution, which indirectly reference the oldest version, I guess it will copy this old version instead of the new one that matches the constraints of other projects? 
I totally agree with you that the 460 projects is not ideal, but honestly, since our solution is composed of 10 different applications, that use a lot of common code, with some features that can be enabled/disabled on the setup depending on the license, we don't have much choice

Comment: @canton7 Is this supported in Visual Studio? I mean, what if I add a new package, will its version be set in this file? Also, is there a way to generate it based on all the packages used in the solution?

Comment: @J4N I'm going to disagree that you do not have much choice. We have an system with more than 10 executables, and only around a hundred or so projects, and that is still way to many. You mention licenses and features, but these have nothing to do with how you organize your projects.

Comment: @JonasH What would you advise then? We could split the solution into several git repository, but then the model should be imported everytime. When we add a new data type, we have to provide adapter for the data acquisition, data storage formater, data exporter, data displayer for each plot for each app. It's definitely possible, but it's kind of a hell to maintain it because when you add something you then have to commit on several solutions

Comment: @J4N I admit that architecturing projects and dependencies is complex and difficult. Using multiple repositories is an option, but it is most useful for libraries used by *independent* applications. But in my experience, a large number of projects is often the result of people not knowing what existing project to put some new functionality in, so they just create a new project. The more projects you have, the more appealing it is to create just one more, since trying to understand the project dependency graph becomes so difficult. But this is just my experience, ymmv.

Comment: And the way to approach this problem is to take a long hard look at the project dependency diagram. Can you merge any projects? Is there a good reason to keep some projects separate? What parts are tightly coupled, and what parts should be loosely coupled? What different "domains" are there? Can you use folders/namespaces instead of projects to separate components? Once you have found some rules about what goes where, write them down. Whenever adding a new project, think a little bit extra if it could go into an existing project instead.

Comment: [Binding redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions#manually-edit-the-app-config-file) should be the correct way in this situation. :)

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT I agree that it would solve the solution, but it's kind of a patch for the original issue, painful to maintain up to date(we have 400 projects and 9 executable, sso I let you imagine the number of binding redirect to create). Especially since depending on which project last, you will not get the same DLL in the output repository. It may add some hard to reproduce bugs.